# Apache Configuration add object instead of String

Tags: java, string, object, data-conversion, apache-commons-config

I have a problem with apache Configuration. Is it possible to add objects and not the string representation of them?

For example, I would like to save the whole 'SiteNode' and not the "toString()" variant:

```
public void persistSiteTree(Context context, Configuration config) {
    List<SiteNode> nodes = Model.getSingleton().getSession().getNodesInContextFromSiteTree(context);
    config.addProperty(CONFIG_PROPERTY_AUTHORISATION, nodes);
}

public void loadSiteTree(Context context, Configuration config) {
    List<Object> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    nodes = config.getList(CONFIG_PROPERTY_AUTHORISATION, nodes);
    if(nodes != null && !nodes.isEmpty()) {
        // Load in sites tree
        SiteNode node = (SiteNode) nodes.get(0); // Gives error as String cannot be cast to "SiteNode"
    }
}
```

But when I call 'loadSiteTree' it gives me String cannot be case to SiteNode. Is it possible for Apache to save the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are overloaded versions of `getList()` supporting a data type conversion to a specific target class.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/ImmutableConfiguration.html#getList-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.util.List-).

> `<T> List<T> getList(Class<T> cls, String key, List<T> defaultValue)`
>
> Get a list of typed objects associated with the given configuration
>   key returning the specified default value if the key doesn't map to an
>   existing object.

Something like this should work for you:

`List<SiteNode> nodes = config.getList(SiteNode.class,CONFIG_PROPERTY_AUTHORISATION, nodes);`

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I do not know why, but this method does not exists in my apache.commons.Configuration. There are 2 variants: The getList(String key) and getList(String key, list<> default)

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 1.9. But I am developing a plugin and therefor cannot change that. The forum of the plugin does not have a section like this so that's why I am asking here (:

Comment: This is available since 2.0 so that is why you can't use it.

Comment: Mhhh thats unfortunate. I guess I'll have to find a workaround then